# Is there any aspect of my JS that could be causing my website to load very slowly?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My website, http://www.denarri.com/, is suddenly taking up to 15-20 seconds to load, when I haven't made any recent changes to it. I've been receiving this same complaint from users on a variety of devices/OS's/browsers.

I tried using Google's [PageSpeed Insight](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights) tool, and the only major issue it found was that one of the images wasn't optimized, but that would only save 450kb, I doubt this would cause the website to load so slowly.

Is there anything upon using "View Page Source" that would indicate what could be causing this? Happy to provide specific parts of my JS, just didn't want to post a wall of code here.

Comment: That's an **8 megabyte** image file you're loading for that background.

Comment: Your biggest culprit seems to be the coffee.jpg background. It took my browser ~25 seconds to load. It can be optimized much further than the suggested compression by the PageSpeed tool.

Comment: [The problem is that background image](http://postimg.org/image/x6g0bo53d/)

Comment: It appears so...time to compress that bad boy. Thank you!

Comment: You're also loading a bunch of web fonts.  The Chrome profiler can show all sorts of details about what's going on in the "Timeline" view.

Answer (score 8):

I have loaded your page and checked what was making it load that slow with the **Google Chrome DevTools** and, as you can see in the screenshot below, the main problem resides in loading that heavy background image (`http://www.denarri.com/img/Background%20photo%20coffee.jpg` - it's almost **8MB**!).

[image: Google Chrome DevTools screenshot]

---

**NOTE:** There's also another image (`http://www.denarri.com/img/screenshot.png`) that took almost a couple of seconds to load.

You have to be careful with images on sites, as they can cause them to take some time to load.

Comment: @ghobs91 if this answers your question, could you mark it as the correct one?